# Not able to bind value to model which is collection asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have list as model in my view. I display my items information and counts. also  I have to take assignedworker to that location from the user. When I submit this method, my collectionmodel is getting null. I am losing all information in my model.

I have data in all the properties except assignedworker. I display all the information to the user using foreach and I take assignedworker name from the user. When I submit this form, List is null.

```
public class Report
    {
        public string itemname{ get; set; }
        public List<itemlocation> locations { get; set; }
    }

public class itemlocation
    {
        public string location { get; set; }
        public List<items> items{ get; set; }        
        public string assignedworker{ get; set; }
    }

View:
@model IList<Report>

<form method="post" asp-action="Report" asp-controller="Home">
 @foreach (var rep in Model)
 {
     <tr>
         <td colspan="3">
            <h3>@rep.itemname</h3>
         </td>
     </tr>
     @foreach (var loc in rep.itemlocation)
     {
         <tr>
             <td>@loc.location </td>
             <td>@loc.items.Count()</td>
             <td>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="worker" name="@loc.assignedworker" value="@loc.assignedworker">
            </td>

        </tr>
     }

  }
</form>
```

I have data in all the properties except assignedworker. I display all the information to the user using foreach and I take assignedworker name from the user. When O submit this form, List is null.

Expected result:

In my controller I would like to be able to see my collection(List) with all the values including assignedworker.

Comment: wheres your controller code

Comment: public IActionResult Report(IList<Report> report)
        {
           if(report!= null && report.Count() !=0)
           // do something
            return View();
        }

Answer (score 0):

In order to generate the right input names for modelbinding, Razor needs the full model expression, which means you must use a regular `for` loop and index your lists, rather than using `foreach`:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    ...
    @for (var j = 0; j < Model[i].locations.Count; j++)
    {
        ...
        <input asp-for="@Model[i].locations[j].assignedworker" />
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I am able to see the assigned worker now but, rest of the information is null. In other words, unit name, location, items is null

Comment: Your not posting any of that. All that exists after the submits the form is what was posted by the form. However, don't just post everything. Only post what the user should be editing. Any other information should be queried from the database again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `<input asp-for="" hidden />` to pass the value to the action:

1.Model:

```
public class Report
{     
    public string itemname { get; set; }
    public List<itemlocation> locations { get; set; }
}
public class itemlocation
{
    public string location { get; set; }
    public List<items> items { get; set; }
    public string assignedworker { get; set; }
}
public class items
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

2.View:

```
 @model IList<Report>

<form method="post" asp-action="Report" asp-controller="Home">
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <input asp-for="@Model[i].itemname" hidden/>
                <h3>@Model[i].itemname</h3>
            </td>
        </tr>

            @for (var j = 0; j < Model[i].locations.Count; j++)
            {  
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Model[i].locations[j].location
                    <input asp-for="@Model[i].locations[j].location" hidden /> 
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Model[i].locations[j].items.Count()
                    @for (var k = 0; k < Model[i].locations[j].items.Count; k++)
                    {
                        <input asp-for="@Model[i].locations[j].items[k].Id" hidden />
                        <input asp-for="@Model[i].locations[j].items[k].name" hidden />
                    }
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input asp-for="@Model[i].locations[j].assignedworker" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        }
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</form>
```